# Unable to use readlink for /proc/self/exe for a C program

Tags: c, shell

```
int len = readlink (filename, target_path, sizeof (target_path));
char buffer[1024];

if(len ==-1)
{
    perror("readlink");
}

else
{
    target_path[len] = '\0';
    printf("executable path: %s\n", target_path);
}
```

This is my code for the relevant section. The only output I get is `readlink: No such file or directory` when what I need is the name the executable ie, a.out.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: could you provide the code with `ssize_t length = readlink("/proc/self/exe",target_path,sizeof (target_path));`. have you tested with a hardcoded path ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<signal.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char filename[1000];
    printf("pid --- %s\n",argv[1]);
    sprintf(filename,"/proc/%s/status",argv[1]);
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    FILE *fp;

    char state,buf[1024];
    fgets(buf,1024,f);
    fgets(buf,1024,f);
    sscanf(buf, "State: %c\n", &state);
    printf("process state = %c\n", state);
    fclose(f);
    char target_path[1024];
    sprintf(filename, "/proc/%s/exe",argv[1]);
    int len = readlink (filename, target_path, sizeof (target_path));
    char buffer[1024];
    if(len ==-1)
    {
        perror("readlink");
    }
    else
    {
        target_path[len] = '\0';
        printf("executable path: %s\n", target_path);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The problem was in my sprintf statement. Incorrect syntax *facepalm*.